# How to record mpeg using different thread in SoQtExaminerViewer?

Tags: c++, multithreading, qt, opengl, openinventor

I would like to record mpeg video from camera movement in `SoQtExaminerViewer`. The initial problem is that when I called `SoMpegNavRenderer::stop()`, the viewer has to wait for the code to complete. Thus, I tried to use `std::thread()` and `std::async()` to create new thread that will handle the recording of mpeg video. I believed, the recording already happen in the background and able to create the video.

However, (this is the one that i need help and understanding) when the code reached `SoMpegNavRenderer::stop()` the view/render area in `SoQtExaminerViewer` replay/redraw back the mpeg video from beginning before the user are able to take control of the viewer. My intention is that for user to press <kbd>r</kbd> to record, do some camera movement, and press <kbd>c</kbd> to stop recording, save the video and continue with their work.

Below is the complete code:

```
#include <Inventor/nodes/SoLightModel.h>
#include <Inventor/nodes/SoOrthographicCamera.h>
#include <Inventor/nodes/SoSeparator.h>
#include <Inventor/nodes/SoMaterial.h>
#include <Inventor/nodes/SoTransform.h>
#include <Inventor/nodes/SoCone.h>
#include <Inventor/Qt/viewers/SoQtExaminerViewer.h>
#include <Inventor/events/SoKeyboardEvent.h>
#include <Inventor/nodes/SoEventCallback.h>
#include <Inventor/MPEG/SoMPEGNavRenderer.h>

// Use Open Inventor's portable thread classes
#include <Inventor/threads/SbThread.h>

SoQtExaminerViewer *myViewer;
SoMPEGNavRenderer *MPEGRenderer;

// Forward decls
SoGroup *getConeGroup(SbVec3f color) ;
void myKeyPressCB (void *, SoEventCallback *eventCB); 
void startRecord();
void* stopRecord(void *userData);

int main(int, char **argv)
{
  // Initialize Open Inventor. --------------------------------------
  QWidget *myWindow = SoQt::threadInit(argv[0]); // pass the app name
  myWindow->resize(500,500);    
  if (myWindow == NULL) 
    return 1;

  // Create scene graph ----------------------------------------------
  SoSeparator *root = new SoSeparator();
  root->ref();

  SoLightModel *lModel = new SoLightModel ;
  lModel->model = SoLightModel::BASE_COLOR ;
  root->addChild(lModel) ;

  SoOrthographicCamera *camera = new SoOrthographicCamera();
  camera->ref();
  root->addChild(camera);

  root->addChild(getConeGroup(SbVec3f(1.0,0.0,0.0)));

  SoEventCallback *myEventCB = new SoEventCallback;
  myEventCB->addEventCallback(SoKeyboardEvent::getClassTypeId(),
                               myKeyPressCB, myViewer);
  root->addChild(myEventCB);

  // Create viewer ---------------------------------------------------
  myViewer = new SoQtExaminerViewer(myWindow);
  myViewer->setSceneGraph(root);
  myViewer->setTitle("Movie with thread");
  myViewer->show();

  // Create mpegrenderer ---------------------------------------------
  MPEGRenderer = new SoMPEGNavRenderer (myViewer->getSceneManager()->getSceneGraph());
  MPEGRenderer->setSize (SbVec2s (300, 300));
  MPEGRenderer->adjustNumFramesPerSecond(TRUE);
  MPEGRenderer->setBitPerSec(-1);
  MPEGRenderer->setCompressionRate(0.);
  MPEGRenderer->setShareContext( (myViewer->getShareContext()));

  int i = 0;
  char mpegFileName[20] = "MPEGOutput.mpg";
  while (!MPEGRenderer->openFile(mpegFileName)) 
  {
    sprintf(mpegFileName, "MPEGOutput%d.mpg", i);
    i++;
  }

  SoQt::show(myWindow);  
  SoQt::mainLoop();     
  delete myViewer;
  root->unref();
  SoQt::finish();
  return 0;
}

void* stopRecord(void *userData)
{
  SoDB::threadInit(); 

  // Get pointer to mpegrenderer
  SoMPEGNavRenderer *pMpegRenderer = (SoMPEGNavRenderer *)userData;
  pMpegRenderer->stop();
  pMpegRenderer->closeFile();

  return NULL;
}

void startRecord()
{
  MPEGRenderer->record();
}

void myKeyPressCB (void *, SoEventCallback *eventCB) 
{
  const SoEvent *event = eventCB->getEvent();

  // check for the keys being pressed
  if (SO_KEY_PRESS_EVENT(event, R)) 
  {    
    startRecord();
  } 
  else if (SO_KEY_PRESS_EVENT(event, C)) 
  {
    SbThread *pModifyThread = SbThread::create(stopRecord, (void*)MPEGRenderer);
  }
  else if (SO_KEY_PRESS_EVENT(event, Z)) 
  {
    exit(0);
  }
}

SoGroup *getConeGroup(SbVec3f color) 
{
  SoGroup *grp = new SoSeparator();
  SoMaterial *mat = new SoMaterial();
  SoCone *cone = new SoCone();
  SoTransform *trans = new SoTransform();

  trans->rotation.setValue(1.0,0.0,0.0,-3.14);
  mat->diffuseColor.setValue(color);
  grp->addChild(mat);
  grp->addChild(trans);
  grp->addChild(cone);

  return grp;
}
```

Comment: I have changed the code from using std::thread to SbThread from open inventor. However the same problem still exist.

Comment: I have no ideas what openinventor is, but judging by `opengl` tag - each thread uses their own opengl context, you cannot freely share the same context between multiple threads. Which means you have to keep all opengl calls within the same thread.

Comment: Thank you for your insight. I do not know how open inventor actually made the call to opengl, yet since all opengl calls has to be in the same thread, that may the problem lie. I am going to search more on that. As for Open Inventor, it is built on top of OpenGL, it's API made the call from CPU to OpenGL's API to execute something in GPU. I am sorry for my bad explanation. You may google for Open Inventor for better understanding.

Comment: Update: SoMpegNavRenderer actually render the video onscreen thus, when run in single thread, the screen freeze, and with multithreading, the screen will replay back the recorded frame. I moved to SoOffScreenRenderer to save the recorded frame in sequence of images and use ffmpeg libraries to create video out of it. This is not the solution but as alternative to my problem. I leave the thread for further discussion. Thank you.